# Would there be significantly more memory used between two classes split from one original one?

Tags: performance, memory

For example, I'm working on a project that creates a student transcript that takes input and creates courses, and displays all the semesters/courses while also keeping track of all the semesters' stats and GPA. Currently, I have a Semester class that has the following methods:

```
Constructor            - Creates a new semester with a given semester name
Is Valid Semester      - Confirms semester name is legal
Add Course             - Adds the given course
Search Course          - Gives index of course in list, or -1 if not found
Remove Course          - Removes the given course if it exists
Withdraw Course        - Withdraws a course from semester
Calc GPA               - Calculates the overall GPA of the semester
To String              - Displays one-line summary of semester
Console menu           - Command-line menu for semester editor
Prompt Course List     - Command prompts for courses to add them from console input
Prompt Remove Course   - Command prompt for adding a course
Prompt Withdraw Course - Command prompt for withdrawing a course
Display Semester       - Display detailed output of semester and its courses' info
```

I know logic and IO should always be separate, and they certainly are separate on a method basis (in other words, all io functionality is decoupled from logic methods). However, I was considering splitting the class to have a separate SemesterIO class with all static methods. Would this cause much more memory or processing time to be used? I know methods within a class are stored in memory "once" and all its instances point to that reference. However, what happens when you have multiple classes versus just one class?

Comment: When talking about performance the first question should always be: **is performance relevant** in this case. How long does the computation currently take? How fast does it have to be?

Comment: Depends on the language, platform, compiler... But "much more"? Probably not. Would it be reasonable, if it would be just static methods and done only to artificially decouple things?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen "Would it be reasonable, if it would be just static methods and done only to artificially decouple things?" That is a much more succinct rephrasing of what I was asking. You're right that it would be to artificially decouple them, also. They'd both still be there every time together. What would be a "best practice" in this case?